# Parse big CSV while validating data consistency

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencsv

I'm designing a new resource for a SpringBoot application which must meet the following requirements:

- Receive a CSV as input. Every row of this file corresponds with a specific entity in my domain.
- Validate consistency of each row. This basically includes obtaining data from the database, to check its existence (i.e., data in column X exists in my database).
- Insert into database all valid entities.

So far, my approach has been:

1. Parse CSV into beans using [OpenCSV](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).
2. Perform necessary validations for each parsed bean (using multithreading).
3. Bulk insert valid beans into the database.

Steps 1 and 3 are good performance-wise, but step 2 is taking 24 mins for 284k rows, which is quite a lot. I have no clue on how to optimise it. I'd like to know how could I improve this approach, or even use a completely different approach if necessary.

Comment: For step 2, do you read the database data in batches or row by row?

Comment: @DmitryKhamitov I was doing it row by row (lol). Now I'm retrieving first all the data which I'm going to need to validate and then iterate through the beans. It is much faster now (it takes seconds for 284k rows). Is there any way to improve even more? I really don't know how to estimate what it should take to be considered optimized...

Comment: What is the query and where are the indexes?

Comment: @g00se what do you mean?

Comment: I mean what query is being issued against the table and what indexes are there on the table

Comment: @g00se basically there are several `existsBy...` queries, and the indexes on the table are only the primary keys

Comment: Then if the primary key is not being used, the query will have to do a full table scan most probably and that will be slow